# How use suitscript inside Restlet inside NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, rest, crm, netsuite, erp

I am trying to create a restlet in which i can get the detail of a **Field** in Netsuite.I have tried the following code to get the details.When i run this Restlet by calling the external URL i get an error as:

```
error code: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
error message:TypeError: Cannot call method "getType" of null (login.js$12762#16)
```

I am using following code

```
function getRESTlet(dataIn) {

    var field = nlapiGetField('custitem_cipp');   // specifiy the internalId of the field
        return field.getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields are only on the record, when your RESTlet executes, there is no record loaded.  You need to load the item record then use nlobjRecord.getField

Answer (score 0):

Use a client script to get the record id and send the record id while calling a restlet from client script, there use can use id.getfieldvalue.